# Merging [tag:hotel] with [tag:hotels]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[hotel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotel) and [hotels](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotels) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. It's done

```
updating post history, 9 rows affected (pipe delimited)
posts, 7 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
destroying 'hotel': [hotel] removed from
Tag Synonym hotel -> hotels was approved!
```